# Count unique values whilst building an array of unique values

Tags: php, foreach, count

I have the following foreach loop that returns unique usernames.

```
$my_array = array();
foreach ( $log->results as $entry ) {

        $unData = unserialize( $entry ->data );

        $ref_id = $entry ->ref_id;
        $ref_nick = get_user_meta( $ref_id, 'nickname', true );

    if ( in_array($ref_nick, $my_array) ) {
        continue;
    } 
    $my_array[] = $ref_nick;
    echo $ref_nick;
}
```

I would like to count the usernames so that I can ultimately do HTML template like:

| USERNAME | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 22 |
| Bob | 10 |
| Charlie | 7 |

I first tried creating another foreach loop that uses the `$my_array` rather than the echo but that feels inefficient.

I have tried something like:

```
    if ( in_array($ref_nick, $my_array) ) {
        count++;
        continue;
    }
```

but using this I'm not sure how I can get add the values to an array that would like like

```
array(
    Alice => 22,
    Bob => 10,
    Charlie => 7
)
```

I think I need to build the array like this so I can loop again but in order of highest count first in the HTML template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to build up `$my_array` like this:

```
$my_array = array();
foreach ( $log->results as $entry ) {

        $unData = unserialize( $entry ->data );

        $ref_id = $entry ->ref_id;
        $ref_nick = get_user_meta( $ref_id, 'nickname', true );
   
    if ( array_key_exists($ref_nick, $my_array) ) {
        //nick already exists in array, so add +1 to existing value
            $my_array[$ref_nick] = $my_array[$ref_nick] +1;
        } 
    else { 
        //add new nick to array and set value 1
        $my_array[$ref_nick] = 1;
    }
}
//Sort descending: 
arsort($my_array);

//Finally loop again and build your HTML:
foreach($my_array as $nick => $count) {
   echo '<tr><td>'.$nick.'</td></td>'.$count.'</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: when I var dump my_array, I get { ["Alice"]=> int(1) ["Bob"]=> int(1)} so only recording 1 rather than the correct number https://pastebin.pl/view/c09d2acf

Comment: that last `array_key_exists` edit did it. thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer. Instead of rsort() (sort by keys) has to be arsort()  (sort by values)